# How do I find a user's Active Directory display name in a C# web application?

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm writing a web application which uses windows authentication and I can happily get the user's login name using something like:

```
 string login = User.Identity.Name.ToString();
```

But I don't need their login name I want their DisplayName. I've been banging my head for a couple hours now...

Can I access my organisation's AD via a web application?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

How about this:

```
private static string GetFullName()
    {
        try
        {
            DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + Environment.UserDomainName + "/" + Environment.UserName);
            return de.Properties["displayName"].Value.ToString();
        }
        catch { return null; }
    }
```

Comment: This is the best way to do it for single user propreties.

Comment: Yeah, I'm liking the simplicity of this ALOT, especially since it works. I owe you a drink!

Comment: This did work, but the WINNT:// properties are a lot less comprehesive than the LDAP:// properties (see http://www.rlmueller.net/Name_Attributes.htm) so while this did work, I was unable to get say user's email addresses using the WINNT:// binding

Answer (score 8):

See related question: [Active Directory: Retrieve User information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132277/active-directory-retrieve-user-information)

See also: [Howto: (Almost) Everything In Active Directory via C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/everythingInAD.aspx) and more specifically section "[Enumerate an object's properties](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/everythingInAD.aspx#26)".

If you have a path to connect to a group in a domain, the following snippet may be helpful:

```
GetUserProperty("<myaccount>", "DisplayName");

public static string GetUserProperty(string accountName, string propertyName)
{
    DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry();
    // "LDAP://CN=<group name>, CN =<Users>, DC=<domain component>, DC=<domain component>,..."
    entry.Path = "LDAP://...";
    entry.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure;

    DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
    search.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + accountName + ")";
    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add(propertyName);

    SearchResultCollection results = search.FindAll();
    if (results != null && results.Count > 0)
    {
        return results[0].Properties[propertyName][0].ToString();
    }
    else
    {
            return "Unknown User";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

`string displayName = UserPrincipal.Current.DisplayName;`

Comment: This applies if your web app is using Windows authentication. You'll need the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` assembly and namespace to access `UserPrincipal`.

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone cares I managed to crack this one:

```
      /// This is some imaginary code to show you how to use it

      Session["USER"] = User.Identity.Name.ToString();
      Session["LOGIN"] = RemoveDomainPrefix(User.Identity.Name.ToString()); // not a real function :D
      string ldappath = "LDAP://your_ldap_path";
      // "LDAP://CN=<group name>, CN =<Users>, DC=<domain component>, DC=<domain component>,..."


      Session["cn"] = GetAttribute(ldappath, (string)Session["LOGIN"], "cn");
      Session["displayName"] = GetAttribute(ldappath, (string)Session["LOGIN"], "displayName");
      Session["mail"] = GetAttribute(ldappath, (string)Session["LOGIN"], "mail");
      Session["givenName"] = GetAttribute(ldappath, (string)Session["LOGIN"], "givenName");
      Session["sn"] = GetAttribute(ldappath, (string)Session["LOGIN"], "sn");


/// working code

public static string GetAttribute(string ldappath, string sAMAccountName, string attribute)
    {
        string OUT = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(ldappath);
            DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(de);
            ds.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName=" + sAMAccountName + "))";

            SearchResultCollection results = ds.FindAll();

            foreach (SearchResult result in results)
            {
                OUT =  GetProperty(result, attribute);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception t)
        {
            // System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(t.Message);
        }

        return (OUT != null) ? OUT : string.Empty;
    }

public static string GetProperty(SearchResult searchResult, string PropertyName)
    {
        if (searchResult.Properties.Contains(PropertyName))
        {
            return searchResult.Properties[PropertyName][0].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a CodePlex project for [Linq to AD](http://www.codeplex.com/LINQtoAD), if you're interested.

It's also covered in the book *[LINQ Unleashed for C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672329832)* by Paul Kimmel - he uses the above project as his starting point.

*not affiliated with either source - I just read the book recently*