# Construct full name from Active Directory like outlook/lync

Tags: c#, active-directory, outlook, lync

I would like to construct the full name based on Active Directory and show it like whart I can see in Outlook / Lync .
I tried to handle case by case but I believe there is general case for that and what I reached till now:

**LastName, FirstName MiddleName (DisplayNameExtension)**

like **Thabet, Mohammed Ali (XYZ Enterprise)**

Please let me know if you have the general pattern ?

Comment: What kind of approach do you use to connect to the ActiveDirectory? Please show us your code. In general there is a fullName property in ActiveDirectory for many objects, please have a look here, they discuss on similar topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246520/how-do-i-find-a-users-active-directory-display-name-in-a-c-sharp-web-applicatio

Comment: The full name which AD returned is : Mohammed Thabet but if you go to e.g. Lync you will find full name contact is :Thabet, Mohammed Ali (XYZ Enterprise) I need to simulate what outlook/Lync showed . I need to get the pattern which Lync construct full name so the issue is not with AD or C# just need to know pattern . I hope I can show my issue clearly .

Comment: Are you using DirectoryEntry to get the data from AD? If so, then you can get all the properties from you entry, and check which one would be suitable for you. What Lync displays is probably a concatenation of a few properties formatted, like "{Lastname}, {FirstName} ({CompanyName})".

Comment: I used DirectoryEntry and till now the pattern that can match is :  "{Lastname}, {FirstName} {MiddleName} ({CompanyName})".  I am afraid that if I would implement this pattern , I found some cases missing so I need to make sure if this is Lync/Outlook pattern or not ?

Comment: You will never be sure unless you find in Google what data Lync is displaying. I doubt if they explain what they display to such level of detail. If Lync is written in .NET you could potentially use DotNetReflector to investigate how they connect to Active Directory and what they display (which I'm not sure is OK to do from the legal perspective, so I do not advise this ;-)). I would suppose if there is no company I would just ommit the "({CompanyName})" part ;-). The same if there is no MiddleName.

Comment: And that is the question I googled for but I can not find answer so I came here to post this question :)