# Getting the display name from a domain \ alias combo

Tags: c#, identity, dns

Apologies for not knowing the right way to phrase this question.

Given a domain name and an alias, for example CONTOSO\steveh how can I get the friendly display name for that alias? For example, in Outlook email sent to CONTOSO\steveh appears as 'Steve Holt'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using .net 3.5, add references to System.DirectoryServices and System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement and try this:

```
        PrincipalContext c = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,"CONTOSO");
        UserPrincipal principal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(c,"steveh");
        Console.WriteLine(principal.DisplayName);
```

I can't verify if it works for a domain since I'm running on a standalone machine but it should help you get started.

Comment: It works fine for domains as well (just tried out your code sample).

Answer (score 0):

You can query ActiveDirectory through LDAP I recommend taking a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132277/active-directory-retrieve-user-information) which has some basic information.  You should be able to get a general direction from there.